# Android Gradle 3.0 how to exclude multi groups

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

As we know, in `Gradle` previous 3.0 version, we can exclude multi groups and modules by following code:

```
compile('com.lean.util:jiabujia:2.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

but in **`Gradle 3.0`** how can I achieve the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried to change `compile` to `api`?

Comment: @azizbekian unfortunately, as the Gradle 3.0 doc[https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html] said, the Gradle change the compile to implemention, and if I simply change the compile to implemention , it not worked

Comment: The alternative of `compile` is `api`. `implementation` has a weaker visibility. Have you tried `api` instead of `implementation`?

Answer (score 0):

As of gradle 3.0 you have to do this now:

```
 android.testVariants.all { variant ->
variant.getCompileConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:  'okhttp'
variant.getCompileConfiguration().exclude group:'com.android.support' , module: 'appcompat-v7'
variant.getRuntimeConfiguration().exclude group:'com.android.support' , module:  'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Please check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: Why is it `getCompileConfiguration()` for first one and `getRuntimeConfiguration()` for second?

Comment: It states `To exclude certain app dependencies from your test configurations, you must do it at execution time using the Variant API`. Is the author asking about test configuration?

Comment: I have checked the doc, I want to know how to exclude **multi** groups

Comment: but what if I exclude the specific dependency's group or modules such as `com.lean.util:jiabujia:2.5.0`, as the result I state in the question.